# Values for saved data and saved requests much lower in CloudFlare analytics for several months

Tags: analytics, cache, statistics, cloudflare

For several months now the pie charts in my CloudFlare analytics show a much smaller value for the saved data and saved requests (around 5%).

Before this the pie charts showed a saving of around 50% since I was using CloudFlare (2013).

Do you also see this change and can confirm this?

Nothing was changed on the server-side and all my domains are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a support ticket & CloudFlare can assist. We recently made some changes to analytics to make them more stable and accurate, so that could be part of the issue there (we were having some issues with analytics over the past few months).

Comment: Already done but got no helpful and got the answer that it would be normal (such a big difference / wrong stats for months - years). Also found no blogpost about this.